# Print portion of line in unix till specified number of matches

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have file a that contains

```
aORbORcORdORe
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6OR7OR8OR10OR11OR
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR
pORcORqOR
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6OR7OR
helloORhiORhiORhiORhiORhi
mORtORqORfAND
pORcORqOR
```

I'm able to grep for lines that contain OR and count number of appearances. But now I want to

1. grep for lines that contains more than 5 OR s in that file to another file called output.txt.
   So output.txt contains

   ```
   1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6
   1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR
   1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6OR7OR
   helloORhiORhiORhiORhiORhi
   ```
2. From output.txt, specify 3 ORs --> it should display the line till 5 OR occurrences

   ```
   1OR2OR3OR4
   1OR2OR3OR4
   1OR2OR3OR4
   helloORhiORhiORhiORhi
   ```
3. from output.txt, specity 7 ORs --> it should display the line till 7 ORs

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: For part 1 you can use `for i in $( ls | grep OR ); do [[ $( echo $"i" | grep -o OR | wc -l ) -gt 5 ]] && echo $"i" ;done > output.txt`

Comment: Thank you Cyrus. Below is my code that I tried so far: #!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Query\tOR\tAND\tfrom\tsize" >> test
while read line ; do
echo -n -e "$line\t" >> test
echo -n "$line" | grep -o "OR" | wc -l | tr -d '\n' >> test
echo -n -e "\t" >> test
echo -n "$line" | grep -o "AND" | wc -l | tr -d '\n' >> test
echo -n -e "\t" >> test
echo -n "$line" |sed -n -e 's/^.*\(from=\)//p' | cut -d "&" -f1 | tr -d '\n'  >> test
echo -n -e "\t" >> test
echo -n "$line" |sed -n -e 's/^.*\(size=\)//p' | cut -d "&" -f1  | tr -d '\n' >> test
echo -n -e "\t" >> test
done < 80oct.csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

**Task 1:**

```
awk -F 'OR' 'NF>5' file > output.txt

cat output.txt
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6OR7OR8OR10OR11OR
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR
1OR2OR3OR4OR5OR6OR7OR
helloORhiORhiORhiORhiORhi
```

**Task 2:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="OR"} {NF=4}1' output.txt
1OR2OR3OR4
1OR2OR3OR4
1OR2OR3OR4
1OR2OR3OR4
helloORhiORhiORhi
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava. I shall try this and get back.